# Numerical evaluation of derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function defined as

```
L[t_] := exp[-0.9239*t]*(0.2310 cos[0.3827*t] + 0.0957*sin[0.3827*t]) + exp[-0.3827*t]*(0.0957 cos[0.9239*t] + 0.2310*sin[0.9239*t]);
```

I wish to evaluate the derivative and second derivative of L at t=0, *numerically*, meaning that a float number of the derivatives at zero.

I have tried all of the below but none seems to produce the desired result:

```
L''[0]
N[L''[0]]
Evaluate[L''[0]]
ND[L''[t], t, 0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: ALL built-in Mathematica functions/symbols start with a capital letter: `exp` should be`Exp`, `sin` should be `Sin`, `cos` should be  `Cos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **correct your expression**:

```
L[t_] := Exp[-0.9239*t]*(0.2310 Cos[0.3827*t] + 
     0.0957*Sin[0.3827*t]) + 
  Exp[-0.3827*t]*(0.0957 Cos[0.9239*t] + 0.2310*Sin[0.9239*t])
```

Notice the capital letters (**this *is* your problem here!!**).

Second. There are many methods to do what you want, for example:

```
D[L[t], {t, 2}];
% /. t -> 0
```

or:

```
L''[0]
```

In both cases, you find that the derivative is `-0.135352`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes by switching to the right built-in function the problem is solved.